# modx how to filter out all resources with pagetitle starting on a spesific letter?

Tags: modx

I have this resources with pagetitles:

[Resource-tree at svalbardflora.net http://svalbardflora.net/modxrev/svalbardflora_net_modxrev_manager_index_php.png](http://svalbardflora.net/modxrev/svalbardflora_net_modxrev_manager_index_php.png)

How can I, in getResources, filter out only the documents with pagetitle starting on **p** or **a to b** or **e to g** (and not a container, but I know how to do that part)?

Answer (score 2):

Xpdo query example:

```
$c = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
$c->where(array(
    'pagetitle:REGEXP' => '^([a-b]|[e-g]|p){1}(.*)$'
    ,'isfolder' => 0
));
$d = $modx->getCollection('modResource',$c);
```

If you'd like to use this in getResources snippet just add pagetitle and isfolder condition to "where" property like this has been done [there](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources#getResources-Examples)

Comment: Thanks! Great. But now i am unfortunately stuck in dots and slashes. Can you please help me to get this correct. This example is the call to show all documents starting on the letter "p": [[getResources?parents=`3` &depth=`4` &tpl=`photoListSort` &display=`all` &sortby=`pagetitle` &sortdir=`ASC` &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1` &tvPrefix=`` &hideContainers=`1` &where=`{"pagetitle:=":REGEXP => '^([p]){1}(.*)$',"isfolder:=":0}` ]]

Comment: There is mistake in 'where' condition. I'm using => as it is array.
Where condition waiting for JSON. You have to try this:
&where=`{"pagetitle:REGEXP" : "^([p]){1}(.*)$","isfolder:=":0}`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @proxyfabio for great help and to guide me in the right direction.

I got the easiest way thanks to @sottwell in the modx forums:

```
&where=`{"pagetitle:LIKE":"p%"}`
```

and

```
&where=`{"pagetitle:LIKE":"l%","OR:pagetitle:LIKE":"m%","OR:pagetitle:LIKE":"n%","OR:pagetitleon:LIKE":"o%"}`
```

As easy as that.